# Seeking a free service that backs up my photos

Tags: cloud, storage, photo

Where can I find a free service that backs up my photos and keeps the original resolution?

Comment: Hello! I'm sorry but this kind of question is considered off-topic here as it is apparently not related to a programming problem. Furthermore, questions about external services are considered off-topic, too!

Answer (score 0):

Get a Myra Cloud account. 100 GB.

https://myra.cloud

You could use Google Photos as well, but be careful, because it will only back up the first 15 GB in full resolution, then you have to decide if you will reduce the resolution or pay for their service. Worse yet, if you are using Gmail, these 15 GB are shared with your Gmail and if you run out of space in Google Photos, then you run out in Gmail as well!